# Magento 2.3 Overiding Invoice PDF not working

Tags: magento2

I want to edit my Invoice in Magento 2.3. I have copied the file from the core file.

> app\Vendor\Magento\magento-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

To :

> app\design\frontend{Theme}{Name}\Magento_Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

Changes I have made in my custom theme PDF file(Invoice.php) it's not reflecting in the PDF.

Please let me know is there anything else I have to change.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot override like that, you need to use preference to do that on your custom module....

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Can you please send any reference link, Thanks.

Comment: Added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom module in your `app/code` directory and then you can override below file in that module

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

You need to create one `di.xml` file here in your Custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

And then you need to override your `Invoice.php` file in your custom module here on this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    /*You can override function of 'Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice' file here based on your requirement. */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,
            $data
        );
    }
}
```

How to create your custom module ? You can [check here](https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-print-hello-world)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I am getting this error Class 'Canisys\Pdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice' not found in /var/www/html/beta/app/code/Canisys/Pdf/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php.

Comment: @SudhakarSJ, You've created custom module and run deployment commands after that Right ?

Comment: Yes. I have run this command. php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: After running the compile command I am getting above error.

Comment: Okay let me check from my side and inform you. Give me some time

Comment: Okay. Thanks...

Comment: I've corrected code in this line. **
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice** in extended model file. Can you please add **\** before Magento ? Then it will work.

Comment: Ok, Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Okay let me know status after it.

Comment: That error has gone, I getting a new error or warning.In ClassReader.php line 35:

  Class Canisys\Pdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Config does not exist

Comment: Can you please let me know how many files you've created in your custom module ? just di.xml amd Invoice.php or any other files you have created there ?

Comment: di.xml,module.xml, Invoice.php, in the Items folder AbstractItems.php and the invoice folder DefaultInvoice.php.   Total of five files I have created

Comment: I think registration.php file is missing in your custom module.

Comment: I forgot to mention that file also I have created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100734/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-sudhakar-sj).

Answer (score 1):

Create custom module if you do not have any which will be under **app/code** folder

For more info about creating custom module : [Visit here](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

Then add di.xml under

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

then add the below code to there

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

then add the destination class which you want to override the core file i.e., Invoice.php

Add the Invoice.php in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

then modify the changes as per your requirements.

More about overriding using preference [visit here](https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have created the custom module, copied the Invoice file from the core file. When I tried to print pdf from the admin side. I got this error (1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Canisys\Pdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice does not exist)

Comment: @SudhakarSJ Please check if there are any spelling mistakes as I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use preference to ovveride,it will works,or use plugin to change the function.